# PyAutoGui While loop keep going when if statement remains true

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've just started learning python and started working on a project.

I'm moving my mouse cursor from one area to another. I just want it to stop when it reach a certain point/area/zone. I'm using the mouse position to tell me where it is, currently.

For some reason, when this loops starts, it keeps looping even when the IF statement is true.

But if I started when the IF statement is true, the loops kinda works as intended, so far it's only reading the 'X' values.

I couldn't find an answer to this, or any questions like it. If anyone has an idea or can point me to a similar post, I'll appreciate it.

```
import pyautogui, sys, time, autoit

#Search for a position on screen manually
try:
    while True:
        x, y = pyautogui.position()
        print(pyautogui.position())
        print('Stopping for 1 seconds, keep searching or CTRL + C to end')
        time.sleep(1)
#Confirmed location on screen.
        if pyautogui.position(x,y) >= pyautogui.position(710, 15):
            pyautogui.leftClick()
            print('The Eagle has landed')
            print(pyautogui.position())
            break
```

Update: I got it! Following mkrieger1 advice, I manage to get the 'x, y' values to update. Code was rewritten.

Comment: Do you ever see the output "The Eagle has landed"?

Comment: You seem to think that `x` and `y` will somehow change during the loop. That is not the case, they will keep the values they were assigned to in `x, y = pyautogui.position()` at the beginning.

Comment: @mkreiger Oh yes, that is the case. I completely forgot about about that haha. Is there a way to have x, y change themselves whenever the mouse moves? I'm thinking on creating another while loop for that. The other problem is the coordinate (x, y), the y value doesn't get saved or read, it only looks for the x when stopping the loop.
And I do see the output for the last Print function.

Comment: True isn't callable.